# Faux getter/setter functions in C returning wrong value

Tags: c, return-value, getter-setter, mutators

Please help? I'm at a bit of a loss here.

main.c:

```
int main(){
    double x = 12.345;
    set_alpha(x);
    double y = get_alpha();
    printf("%f\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

block.c:

```
double alpha;
void set_alpha(double a){
    alpha = a;
    printf("%f\n", alpha);
}
double get_alpha(){
    return alpha;
}
```

When running `gcc block.c main.c`, I get

```
12.345000
183898224.000000
```

, where the latter number changes at random. What's going on and how do I fix my faux getter/setter functions?

Comment: You see, if you had compiled with `gcc -Wall block.c main.c` you would have seen quite a lot of warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have **prototypes** for get and set_alpha then the compiler doesn't know what their parameters and return values are. Each source file is compiled independently. If the prototypes aren't listed in `main.c` then the compiler has to guess at the function signatures. It wrongly guesses that everything's an `int`, as in `int set_alpha(int a)` and `int get_alpha()`. Oops!

The fix:

```
void set_alpha(double a);
double get_alpha();

int main() {
    ...
}
```

The best thing to do is to create a separate header file `block.h` and put the prototypes there. Also to make sure to enable all your compiler's warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall`) so you don't get bit by this again.

#### block.h

```
#ifndef BLOCK_H
#define BLOCK_H 

void set_alpha(double a);
double get_alpha();

#endif
```

#### main.c

```
#include "block.h"

int main() {
    ...
}
```

#### block.c

```
#include "block.h"

...
```

Comment: I was just debugging this, and it almost looked like the return value wasn't being stored properly. Good catch, +1

Comment: Oh my god, that was the problem. I had a `block.h`, but I was `#include`ing it in my `block.c` file, not my `main.c`. Could you explain why this makes the difference?

Comment: Like he mentioned, gcc saw that `get_alpha` hadn't been declared, so it assumed it just returned an `int` (ooold compatibility reasons). Due to the way `int`s and `double`s are returned on x86 (I assume you're running on an x86 platform), the return will probably be garbage